# How to get foreign data in the WCF

Tags: c#, database, wcf, foreign-keys

It's WCF Project.

I have a Event Entity and EventStatus Entity. EventStatus is the foreign table of Event.

Now, I use

```
 public IQueryable<Event> RetrieveAllEvent() 
        {
            return context.EventSet;
        }
```

To get the Event.
And I see the Content like this:

```
    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
```

I will get a error:
[image]

So, If i make context false:

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

I can get the data from DB. But I cannot get the EventStatus.The length of it is 0.

But now, I have to get the data.
How to do it ?

(By the way, I have the     [Serializable][DataContract][DataMember])

Answer (score 0):

The problem is between EntityFramework and serialization of WCF, which it can not serialize proxy instances created by Entityframework when ProxyCreation is enabled.

The simple solution is
1. Set

```
 context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

2. Then in your query, include EventStatus for EntityFramework eager loading

```
public IEnumerable<Event> RetrieveAllEvent() 
    {
        return context.EventSet.Includes("EventStatus").ToList();
    }
```

Another solution: you should not expose model of EntityFramework directly to WCF service, create a separate model for WCF and in that model it only provides enough information for your service (with this approach, you can turn on/off lazyloading or proxyCreation whatever you want), for example:

```
[DataContract]
class EventResponse{
   public int Value {get;set;}
}

public IEnumerable<EventResponse> RetrieveAllEvent() 
    {
        return context.EventSet.Select(f=>new EventResponse { Value = f.Value }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I have searched this problem. there is not any article can solve it. I will try, :)

Comment: you say if `LazyLoadingEnabled = false, ProxyCreationEnabled = false,` there is no error, so the error come from `return context.EventSet.Includes("EventStatus").ToList();` ?

Comment: Yes, if i set the include.I will get the error again.

Comment: I think there is something in class `EventStatus` which makes WCF can not serialize. So I think you should go to solution create a wrapper class for Event and EventStatus.

Comment: These are what i have in the EventStatus:[Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public partial class EventStatus
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Status { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Because EventStatus has link to Event which makes circular reference, that causes problem therefore you should use wrapper classes without circular references